# Where should I ask a question about office maintenance? (Specifically, magnetic door holder)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I googled "maintenance stack exchange", but obviously that had undesired results :)

Where can/should I ask questions about office maintenance? I'm leaning toward *[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but I hoped there might be a better option I'm not aware of.

The specific question is about some magnetic door holders (magnets at the top that keep the door open and release if there is a fire).  My hope is that there is a simple switch somewhere to turn these on, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for adding [tag:site-recommendation], didn't see it.

Comment: Please review the list of sites in https://stackexchange.com/sites and share a brief description of your findings.

Comment: @Rubén it needs someone with some experience to tell which site really fits. Just going through the list might be enough, but also with a risk of posting in wrong site, resulting in question being closed. That's why we have the site recommendation tag here, which I'm glad is being widely used.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I'm also happy of having here [tag:site-recommendation] but I also think that this type of questions might be better if the OP review the SE site list first or as part of their continued efforts. Many users didn't know that it exists. By the other hand posting in the wrong site and having a question closed once on a while is not a bad thing and there should not be fear about that. (sidenote: no down / closes  votes on this question so far, actually there isn't any vote yet)

Answer (score 6):

[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) seems the best bet here, and I don't think that the situation of an "office" environment will make your question off-topic:

> Ask about...
>
> - Questions you would typically ask a home contractor.
> - Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task.
> - Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.
> - National building codes (of any country).
> - Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.
> - Carpentry and woodworking.

Comment: Welcome back to the network! Good to see your behatted canine face again :-)